# HTML code downloaded using request.get() is different from actual HTML inspect element code

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so I was trying to scrape this webpage https://mamikos.com/cari/ugm-bulaksumur-caturtunggal-kabupaten-sleman-daerah-istimewa-yogyakarta-indonesia/all/bulanan/0-15000000

using this code

```
header = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36'}
halaman = requests.get('https://mamikos.com/cari/ugm-bulaksumur-caturtunggal-kabupaten-sleman-daerah-istimewa-yogyakarta-indonesia/all/bulanan/0-15000000', headers = header) 
print(halaman)
```

and then when I run this code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(halaman.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

the HTML codes shown are different from the ones that you'll see in the inspect element of the webpage, anyone can help me?

Comment: The DOM Inspector in your browser does not show you the raw HTML source of a page, it shows you the live DOM representation, which is invariably different. Instead you should look at the raw response in the Network tab, or the View Source function.

Comment: it seems that this websites use javascript to modify the pages dynamically so that you get different html codes. You should use some python libraries like [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) to scrape the websites and get datas.